# Capturing Ctrl+W on browser

Tags: javascript, browser, command

First of all, I know there are plenty of questions about this matter already, I've searched for them and most of them are a few years old, that's the main reason I'm asking.

I kinda need to capture <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> Yes or Yes in all browsers (at least the most common ones, Chrome, Firefox and IE11/Edge, maybe Safari).

I'm running an Operative System virtualization inside a div and I want to block the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>, so the browser doesn't close and the user can use this command in its virutalization (and if I can also other commands such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, etc, but the most important one is the close command).

I've looked for plugins, hacks and vanilla JS code but none works, perhaps <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> is the most difficult command to capture. Do you guys know if its possible? And if it is, any ideas on how I could manage to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: browsers haven't changed in those few years, all the answers still apply - onbeforeunload is your best bet

Comment: I'll try to play around onbeforeunload but people in the comments/answer sometime said that didn't work for them. Never the less I'll try it out, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone ends up in here.

As Jaromanda told in the comments section (and many others in other posts)  [window.onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) is our best ally. In this precise case, it doesn't serve me well, as this prompts an alert and I just want to capture it so it doesn't really executes. Haven't found any answer to just capturing Ctrl + W as it's a complex thing to "abort" a close command.

EDIT #1:
It seems the problem is Chrome, you can capture these comands in Firefox (haven't tested them in IE/Edge nor Safari). If by any chance someone knows/comes up with any ideas, they will be gratefully accepted

Comment: you really can not stop an operating system function (i.e. end program) in a web page

Comment: But I can stop Ctrl + S for example, I can caputre it and show a console.log for example :(

Comment: oh, you didn't mention you could do that

Comment: You can capture it in JS, but can't capture ctrl w (or ctrl + T, for example)

Comment: It's really a problem when you press CTRL-W by accident, some people wanted to press CTRL-Z (in enlgish keyboard W is near Z) or CTRL-X (in french keyboard W is near X) but if they press CTRL-W, they lost all there work without any alert box ...
Its the reason why some people want to capture CTRL-W to prevent the user to quit or to stay